# ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['col_1'])

df_x = data.iloc[:, 1:]
df_y = data.iloc[:, 0]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, test_size=0.9, random_state=4)

nn = MLPClassifier(activation='logistic', solver='sgd', hidden_layer_sizes=(2,), random_state=1)
#nn.fit(x_train[x], y_train[x])

print(nn)

nn.fit(x_train, y_test)

pred = nn.predict(x_test)
```

I am getting the error as shown in the title from `.fit()` method, and didn't understand much from the documentation as I am new to ML.

**Full error:**

```
File "C:/NNC/Main.py", line 14, in <module>
    data.target.array([])
  File "C:\NNC\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5179, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target'
```

**Update -:**
I'v since removed and updated this as this was to test a solution found in the documentation. I have updated the error

```
File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\NNC\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 325, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\NNC\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 932, in _validate_input
    multi_output=True)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\NNC\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 739, in check_X_y
    estimator=estimator)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\NNC\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 459, in check_array
    dtype_orig = np.result_type(*array.dtypes)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in result_type
ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: provide complete error message in your question

Comment: all done, thank you

Comment: Seems like the error is outside of the code you provided: ```data.target.array([])``` there's no column```target```...

Comment: Iv since removed and updated this as this was to test a sololution found in the documentation. i have updated the error. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Don't change your question into another question. It will lead lot of down votes on answers. Just add details not remove existing impotent ones.

Comment: Could you provide `data.head()` and `data.info()` to know with what we are dealing with as input.

Answer (score 5):

This error will occur cause of these reasons:

1. You don't have `target` column in your csv. Check twice in your csv.
2. If you have `target` column, there are white space or spaces in your `target` column.
   It may be exist like these

```
< target>
<target >
< target >
<target   >...etc.
```

There for copy that column name with that white spaces. After that run this code

```
data = read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['col_1'])
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
```

**Updated:**

If your data frame look like this

```
       a         b
0      1         2
1      1         2
2      1         2
3      1         2
4      1         2
```

When you use iloc

```
df_y = data.iloc[:, 0]

output -:
       a         
0      1         
1      1         
2      1         
3      1         
4      1
```

```
df_y = data.iloc[:, 1]   

output -:
       b
0      2
1      2
2      2
3      2
4      2
```

In your case you have used `df_x = data.iloc[:, 1:]`. Correct it as `df_x = data.iloc[:, 1]`. Understand how iloc works

Comment: "Understand how iloc works" - or slicing in general.